# How to detect navigation back with child coordinators

Tags: ios, swift

I use coordinator pattern with child coordinators to provide loosely coupled code and accordant with single responsibility principle. To handle with navigating back I've decided to use navigation controller delegate (accordingly with this article https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/175/advanced-coordinator-pattern-tutorial-ios).
But my problem is that I have Home VC with Home Coordinator, next I go to Workout VC with Workout Coordinator and next I go to Exercise VC with Exercise Coordinator.

So I want to have a Workout Coordinator and Exercise Coordinator as children for Home Coordinator.

[image]

And everything seems to be ok, but I have a memory leak between the Workout Coordinator and Exercise Coordinator because I can't delete the exercise coordinator after I use the back button to navigate back. My navigation controller delegate doesn't recognize when I back.

```
class HomeCoordinator: NSObject, Coordinator, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    
    var childCoordinators = [Coordinator]()
    var navigationController: UINavigationController
    
    init(navigationController: UINavigationController) {
        self.navigationController = navigationController
        navigationController.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
        navigationController.navigationBar.largeTitleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor.white]
    }

    func start() {
        navigationController.delegate = self
        let vc = HomeFactory.makeHomeScene(delegate: self)
        navigationController.pushViewController(vc, animated: false)
    }
    
    func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, didShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {

        guard let fromViewController = navigationController.transitionCoordinator?.viewController(forKey: .from) else { return }
        
        if navigationController.viewControllers.contains(fromViewController) {
            return
        }

        if let addWorkoutViewController = fromViewController as? NewWorkoutViewController {
            let workoutCoordinator = addWorkoutViewController.presenter?.workoutCoordinatorDelegate
            childDidFinish(workoutCoordinator)
        }
    }
}

extension HomeCoordinator: HomeCoordinatorDelegate {

    func goToWorkoutCreating() {
        let child = AddWorkoutCoordinator(navigationController: navigationController)
        child.passWorkoutToHomeDelegate = self
        childCoordinators.append(child)
        child.parentCoordinator = self
        child.start()
    }
}

class AddWorkoutCoordinator: NSObject, Coordinator, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    
    var parentCoordinator: Coordinator?
    var exerciseNumber: Int?
    
    weak var passWorkoutToHomeDelegate: PassWorkoutToHome?

    var childCoordinators = [Coordinator]()
    var navigationController: UINavigationController
    
    init(navigationController: UINavigationController) {
        self.navigationController = navigationController
        navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = .white
        
    }
    
    func start() {
        let vc = AddWorkoutFactory.makeAddWorkoutScene(delegate: self)
        navigationController.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
    
    func childDidFinish(_ child: Coordinator?) {
        for (index, coordinator) in childCoordinators.enumerated() {
            if coordinator === child {
                childCoordinators.remove(at: index)
                break
            }
        }
    }


       
// THIS FUNCTION IS NOT RESPOND AT ALL, BUT IT RESPONDS IN HOME COORDINATOR
        func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, didShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
    
        guard let fromViewController = navigationController.transitionCoordinator?.viewController(forKey: .from) else { return }


        if navigationController.viewControllers.contains(fromViewController) {
            return
        }
  
        if let newExerciseViewController = fromViewController as? NewExerciseViewController {
            
//            childDidFinish(newExerciseViewController.presenter?.exerciseCoordinatorDelegate)
//            childDidFinish(newExerciseViewController.presenter!.exerciseCoordinatorDelegate)
        }
    }
}

extension AddWorkoutCoordinator: AddWorkoutCoordinatorDelegate {
    
      func goToAddExercise() {
       
          let child = AddExerciseCoordinator(navigationController: navigationController)
          child.passExerciseToWorkoutDelegate = self
          childCoordinators.append(child)
          child.start()
      }





class AddExerciseCoordinator: NSObject, Coordinator {
    

    weak var passExerciseToWorkoutDelegate: PassExerciseToWorkoutDelegate?
    
    var childCoordinators = [Coordinator]()
    var navigationController: UINavigationController
    
    init(navigationController: UINavigationController) {
        self.navigationController = navigationController
        self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = .white
    }
    
    func start() {
        let vc = AddExerciseFactory.makeAddExerciseScene(delegate: self)
        
        navigationController.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
    
    func startEditExercise(setData: [ExerciseFieldsModel], exerciseName: String) {
        let vc = AddExerciseFactory.makeAddExerciseScene(delegate: self)
        vc.presenter?.textFieldsModel = setData
        vc.exerciseText = exerciseName
        navigationController.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
}

extension AddExerciseCoordinator: NewExerciseCoordinatorDelegate {
    
    func saveExercise(newExercise: ExerciseCellInNewWorkout) {
        navigationController.popViewController(animated: true)
        passExerciseToWorkoutDelegate?.passExerciseToWorkout(exercise: newExercise)
    }
}
```

So basically the problem is that using navigate controller delegate didShow method I need to get the type of "fromViewController", so if I have one child like Workout Coordinator, everything is ok, I cant remove it easily, but when I have one layer deeper, so I have Workout Coordinator and after that Exercise Coordinator I don't know how to use navigation controller delegate didShow method to recognize if Exercise Coordinator is popped. So I have tried to use navigation controller didShow also in Workout Coordinator, but as I wrote in a comment in code, it doesn't respond at all.

Could you help me to get some advice on how to detect if the user taps the back button on exercise VC? Or maybe my conception is bad and only the workout coordinator should be a child and the exercise coordinator should not be.

Comment: Without showing us the rest of the relevant code this is pointless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your ExerciseViewController goes out of scope (gets deleted) it should be notifying the object that pushed it on the navigation controller. It looks like that is your ExerciseCoordinator.

Setup your Coordinator containment system the same way UIKit's view containment system is setup. Where a Coordinator has an `addChild(coordinator:)` method and a `removeFromParent()` method. When the view controller notifies its coordinator that it went out of scope, the coordinator should call its `removeFromParent()` method.

The system above is far better than relying on `didShow` and works for any sort of method of presentation.

Comment: Ok, but I want to avoid involving view controller in notifying its coordinator that view went out of scope. Because what happens when we have multiple view controllers being shown in the child coordinator and e.g. we use viewDidDissapear() to notify coordinator about being out of scope. Then viewWillDissapear will be called prematurely, and our coordinator stack will get confused. This is the reason why i want to use navigation controller delegate.

Comment: Don't use `viewDidDissapear()`. I said to base it on when the view controller is *deleted*, not when it disappears. Think about it this way, as long as the view controller exists, the coordinator should also exist. When the view controller is deleted, the coordinator should also get deleted. Since there are actions in the system that you don't have control over that can delete a view controller (like the navigation back button) you have no choice but track that and respond to it.

Comment: Can I ask you which way do you recommend to notify that vc and coordinator is deleted?

Comment: The Coordinator should be observing the view controller, likely as a delegate. In the `deinit` method of the view controller, you should notify the coordinator through the delegate that the view controller is dead. Just make sure you don't have a strong reference to the view controller in any coordinator...